# Whats the name of this surface $a^2+b^2+c^2+2abc-1=0$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, cubics

Motivation:
Let $a = \cos(\alpha), b = \cos(\beta),c = \cos(\gamma)$ where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are the angles in a triangle.
Then by
$$\alpha+\beta+\gamma = \pi$$
and using $\cos(x+y) = \cos(x)\cos(y)-\sin(x)\sin(y)$, $\sin(\operatorname{acos}(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ we find that the $a,b,c$ are points on the surface:

$$a^2+b^2+c^2+2abc-1=0$$

What is known about this surface, or what is it called?

[a plot of the surface with Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20a%5E2%2Bb%5E2%2Bc%5E2%2B2*a*b*c-1%3D0)

Edit:
With the help of @GEdgar I think I found the name of [this surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_nodal_cubic_surface) by looking at the plots of both surfaces. (Cayley's nodal cubic surface).

> Now the question remains how to show algebraically that they are the
>   same?

**Edit**:
Since every three point metric space [can be isometrically emdedded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764526/proving-that-a-metric-space-with-3-points-can-be-embedded-isometrically-into-m) in $\mathbb{R}^2$, we can build the possibly to a line degenerated triangle from these three points:

Using the law of cosines to define angles, given distances, we find that the quantities:

$$a:=\frac{d(y,z)^2+d(y,x)^2-d(x,z)^2}{2d(y,z)d(x,y)}, $$
$$b:=\frac{d(y,z)^2+d(z,x)^2-d(x,y)^2}{2d(y,z)d(z,x)},$$
$$c:=\frac{d(x,z)^2+d(y,x)^2-d(y,z)^2}{2d(x,z)d(x,y)}$$
satisfy by what was given above the following equation:

$$a^2+b^2+c^2+2abc-1=0$$

hence are points on the Cayley's nodal cubic surface.
For instance for the metric on natural numbers 
$$d(x,y) = \sqrt{\sigma(x)+\sigma(y)-2\sigma(\gcd(x,y))}$$
and for three pairwise distinct primes $p,q,r$ [we get](https://mathoverflow.net/a/343773/6671) the following nice formula:

$$\pi = \operatorname{acos}(\frac{r}{\sqrt{(p+r)(q+r)}})+\operatorname{acos}(\frac{q}{\sqrt{(p+q)(q+r)}})+\operatorname{acos}(\frac{p}{\sqrt{(p+r)(p+q)}})$$

Setting

$$a = \frac{r}{\sqrt{(p+r)(q+r)}}, b= \frac{q}{\sqrt{(p+q)(q+r)}}, c=\frac{p}{\sqrt{(p+r)(p+q)}}$$

we see that those are points on the Cayley nodal cubic surface.

Comment: What do you want to know about it?

Comment: @DietrichBurde: What's the name of this surface? So I can google and find out more about it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $(a+b+c)^2-2(ab+bc+ca)-2abc-1=0$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: For example how to add two points if possible on this surface? (I will edit the question to show motivation for asking this).

Comment: This is a cubic surface (because of $abc$ in there).  Classification of real three-dimensional cubic surfaces was carried out in the 19th century.  I cannot tell you any details of it, however.

Comment: @GEdgar: Thanks for your help!

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I think this is the same as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_nodal_cubic_surface by looking at the plots of both surfaces.

Comment: This is a quite general name, though. But perhaps you find something more specific. Is it related to one of your previous questions?

Comment: @DietrichBurde : Which previous question do you mean?

Comment: I mean to one of your previous questions (so possibly any of them, you will know better than me).

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I edited the question, to clarify the relationship to the previous questions.

Comment: related: https://archive.org/details/some-formulas-for-pi