# Some formulas for $\pi$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, pi

Let $0 < x < y < z$.
Then we have:

$$\pi = \arccos\left(-\frac{\frac{x^{2}}{y^{2}} + \frac{x^{2}}{z^{2}} - \frac{y^{2}}{z^{2}} - 1}{2 \, \sqrt{-\frac{x^{2}}{y^{2}} + 1} \sqrt{-\frac{x^{2}}{z^{2}} + 1}}\right) + \arccos\left(-\frac{\frac{x^{2}}{y^{2}} - \frac{x^{2}}{z^{2}} + \frac{y^{2}}{z^{2}} - 1}{2 \, \sqrt{-\frac{x^{2}}{y^{2}} + 1} \sqrt{-\frac{y^{2}}{z^{2}} + 1}}\right) + \arccos\left(\frac{\frac{x^{2}}{y^{2}} - \frac{x^{2}}{z^{2}} - \frac{y^{2}}{z^{2}} + 1}{2 \, \sqrt{-\frac{x^{2}}{z^{2}} + 1} \sqrt{-\frac{y^{2}}{z^{2}} + 1}}\right)$$

I have a proof for this, but I would like to know if there are other proofs for this.

Here are some formulas I derived using the technique above, which I find amusing:

$$\pi = \arccos\left(\frac{1}{12} \, \sqrt{5} \sqrt{3}\right) + \arccos\left(\frac{5}{32} \, \sqrt{5} \sqrt{2}\right) + \arccos\left(\frac{13}{48} \, \sqrt{3} \sqrt{2}\right)$$

$$\pi = \arccos\left(\frac{1}{24} \, \sqrt{7} \sqrt{5}\right) + \arccos\left(\frac{13}{108} \, \sqrt{7} \sqrt{3}\right) + \arccos\left(\frac{25}{144} \, \sqrt{5} \sqrt{3}\right)$$

$$\pi = \arccos\left(\frac{75}{128}\right) + \arccos\left(\frac{41}{160} \, \sqrt{7}\right) + \arccos\left(\frac{3}{40} \, \sqrt{7}\right)$$

$$\pi = \arccos\left(\frac{41}{500} \, \sqrt{11} \sqrt{5}\right) + \arccos\left(\frac{1}{20} \, \sqrt{11}\right) + \arccos\left(\frac{61}{200} \, \sqrt{5}\right)$$

$$\pi = \arccos\left(\frac{1}{84} \, \sqrt{13} \sqrt{11}\right) + \arccos\left(\frac{61}{864} \, \sqrt{13} \sqrt{6}\right) + \arccos\left(\frac{85}{1008} \, \sqrt{11} \sqrt{6}\right)$$

$$\pi = \arccos\left(\frac{1}{112} \, \sqrt{15} \sqrt{13}\right) + \arccos\left(\frac{85}{1372} \, \sqrt{15} \sqrt{7}\right) + \arccos\left(\frac{113}{1568} \, \sqrt{13} \sqrt{7}\right)$$

$$\pi = \arccos\left(\frac{1}{144} \, \sqrt{17} \sqrt{15}\right) + \arccos\left(\frac{113}{1024} \, \sqrt{17} \sqrt{2}\right) + \arccos\left(\frac{145}{1152} \, \sqrt{15} \sqrt{2}\right)$$

$$\pi = \arccos\left(\frac{1}{180} \, \sqrt{19} \sqrt{17}\right) + \arccos\left(\frac{145}{972} \, \sqrt{19}\right) + \arccos\left(\frac{181}{1080} \, \sqrt{17}\right)$$

$$\pi = \arccos\left(\frac{1}{220} \, \sqrt{21} \sqrt{19}\right) + \arccos\left(\frac{181}{4000} \, \sqrt{21} \sqrt{10}\right) + \arccos\left(\frac{221}{4400} \, \sqrt{19} \sqrt{10}\right)$$

**Edit**:
The proof is based on noticing that every $3$ point metric space can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a triangle and then using trigonometry. (See [Whats the name of this surface $a^2+b^2+c^2+2abc-1=0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3393140/whats-the-name-of-this-surface-a2b2c22abc-1-0) )

The metric space I am considering is a Hilbert space:

$$k(x,y) = \frac{\min(x,y)^2}{\max(x,y)^2}$$

(see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/396061/is-there-a-feature-mapping-for-this-kernel-kx-y-frac-minx-y-maxx-y )

with metric:

$$ d(x,y) = \sqrt{2(1-k(x,y))}$$

For three points $x,y,z$ in a metric space, we can define (using the law of cosines) the following quantity:

$$s(x,y,z) = \frac{d(x,y)^2+d(y,z)^2-d(x,z)^2}{2d(x,y)d(y,z)}$$

Then we can embedd $X \times X \times X$ to the Cayleys surface ( https://mathcurve.com/surfaces.gb/cayley/cayley.shtml ) through the mapping:

$$f(x,y,z) = (s(x,y,z), s(z,x,y),s(y,z,x))$$

We then have:

$$\pi = \arccos(s(x,y,z))+\arccos(s(z,x,y))+\arccos(s(y,z,x))$$

which proves the claim.

Comment: Maybe add a few details about your proof so that people don't _reinvent the wheel_ when answering this question?

Comment: If you have proof, you should provide it; otherwise, how will anyone else know what constitutes an "other" proof? ... Also, your formula is unnecessarily complicated. The first $\arccos$ argument, for instance, reduces to $$\frac{\sqrt{(x^2-y^2)(z^2-x^2)}}{2xz}$$ (Your parameter order would seem to need adjustment to avoid negatives under the square roots.)

Comment: @Blue: Thanks, The complicated part is a point of view... But I will otuline the proof.

Comment: @NoName: Ok, I will outline the proof.

Comment: @Blue: What do you mean with parameter order. If there is a bug in the formula, please feel free to edit it.

Comment: @stackExchangeUser: Looking closer, the sign issue seems quite problematic. Assuming you want real values in the individual square roots, your first term's first square root requires $y<x$, but your second term's first square root requires $x<y$. Even if you allow the individual roots to be imaginary so long as their products are real, then in first term, if $x<y$ then $z<x$; likewise in the third term, if $y<z$ then $z<x$. Both violate your stated order, but the second term respects it. Whatever bug exists is up to you to squash. It might help to state the parameters used in your examples.

Comment: @Blue: The parameters are $(x,y,z) = (k,k+1,k+2)$ where $1 \le k \le 10$.

Comment: @stackExchangeUser: For $(x,y,z)=(1,2,3)$, I (with *Mathematica*) get that the argument of the first term is $\sqrt{-2/3\;}$.

Comment: @Blue: Thanks for the hint. As you noticed, there was a bug in the formula, which should be corrected now. Thanks again.

Comment: @stackExchangeUser: That'll do it. :) ... Sadly, the terms don't all simplify as nicely as before. Now they're 
$$\frac{y^2 + z^2}{2yz}\sqrt{\frac{y^2-x^2}{z^2 - x^2}},\quad 
\frac{\sqrt{(y^2-x^2)(z^2-y^2)}}{2yz}, \quad 
\frac{x^2 + y^2}{2y^2}\sqrt{\frac{z^2-y^2}{z^2-x^2}}$$ Anyway, proving the relation is straightforward, if tedious: the above values are cosines, so calculate corresponding sines as $\sqrt{1-\cos^2}$ (necessarily non-negative, since the angles are in $[0,\pi]$). Taking the cosine of both sides of the formula reduces to $-1=-1$.

Comment: related: https://archive.org/details/some-formulas-for-pi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Defining $\sigma_{uv} := \sqrt{u^2-v^2}$, OP asserts that
$$\pi = \alpha+\beta+\gamma \tag{1}$$
for angles in $[0,\pi]$ satisfying
$$\cos\alpha = \frac{y^2 + z^2}{2yz}\frac{\sigma_{yx}}{\sigma_{zx}}\qquad\cos\beta=\frac{\sigma_{yx}\sigma_{zy}}{2yz} \qquad 
\cos\gamma=\frac{x^2+y^2}{2y^2}\frac{\sigma_{zy}}{\sigma_{zx}}
\tag{2}$$
Note that, since the cosines are non-negative, we may actually take $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ to be first-quadrant angles. Calculating $\sqrt{1-\cos^2}$ to get the corresponding sines (which are non-negative for first-quadrant angles), we (and by "we", I mean *Mathematica*) obtain
$$\sin\alpha=\frac{\tau\sigma_{zy}}{2yz\sigma_{zx}} \qquad
\sin\beta= \frac{\tau}{2yz}\qquad
\sin\gamma=\frac{\tau\sigma_{yx}}{2y^2\sigma_{zx}} \tag{3}$$
where
$$\tau:= \sqrt{4y^2z^2 - \sigma_{yx}^2\sigma_{zy}^2} \tag{4}$$
Now, let's take the cosine of the right-hand side of $(1)$:
$$\begin{align}\cos(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)&=
\cos\alpha\cos\beta\cos\gamma \\
&\quad - \cos\alpha\sin\beta\sin\gamma
- \sin\alpha\cos\beta\sin\gamma 
- \sin\alpha\sin\beta\cos\gamma \tag{5}\\[4pt]
&=
\frac{(y^2+z^2)(x^2+y^2)}{8y^4z^2}\frac{\sigma_{yx}^2\sigma_{zy}^2}{\sigma_{zx}^2} \\
&\quad-\frac{\tau^2}{8y^4z^2\sigma_{zx}^2}\left((y^2+z^2)\sigma_{yx}^2
+\sigma_{yx}^2\sigma_{zy}^2
+(x^2+y^2)\sigma_{zy}^2\right) \tag{6} \\[4pt]
&= \cdots \tag{7} \\[4pt]
&= -1 \tag{8}
\end{align}$$
Thus, $\alpha+\beta+\gamma$ must be an odd multiple of $\pi$; since no one angle exceeds $\pi/2$, we conclude that the sum is specifically $\pi$. $\square$

Comment: Thanks! (+1) Nice calculation.