# Formulas for $\pi$ of the form $2\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k}{k}\frac{a^{2k+1}+b^{2k+1}+c^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$

Tags: trigonometry, power-series, pi, sagemath

**Fourth edit**:
I decided to start an infinite formulas challenge based on the formulas below to be interpreted as music:

**#InfinitePiChallenge:**

Rules:

https://www.reddit.com/r/algorithmicmusic/comments/10cifzg/a_little_challenge/

Here is my interpretation of this challenge:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RdCDsSfe2_E

**Third edit**:

For those interested in the Sagemath-code to produce your own formula, given three natural numbers $x<y<z$, it can be found here. I am sharing those formulas in public domain, for the benefit of all, if there is any:

https://github.com/githubuser1983/generate_formulas_for_pi/blob/main/formulas_for_pi.ipynb

**First edit:**
I have found [a method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4183066/some-formulas-for-pi) which allows one to plug in some numbers $a,b,c$ in this formula and get formulas for $\pi$:

$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( a \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( b \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( c \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$

Some formulas generated this way are:

$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( -\frac{4}{65} \, \sqrt{13} \sqrt{5} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{17}{26} \, \sqrt{2} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{9}{130} \, \sqrt{13} \sqrt{5} \sqrt{2} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$

$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( -\frac{261}{47965} \, \sqrt{181} \sqrt{53} \sqrt{2} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{2071}{47965} \, \sqrt{53} \sqrt{5} \sqrt{2} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{1309}{47965} \, \sqrt{181} \sqrt{5} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( -\frac{931}{96050} \, \sqrt{113} \sqrt{85} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{2061}{19210} \, \sqrt{85} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{1781}{19210} \, \sqrt{113} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( -\frac{19}{2210} \, \sqrt{85} \sqrt{65} \sqrt{2} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{32}{1105} \, \sqrt{85} \sqrt{13} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{53}{2210} \, \sqrt{65} \sqrt{13} \sqrt{2} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( -\frac{96}{12665} \, \sqrt{149} \sqrt{85} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{437}{25330} \, \sqrt{85} \sqrt{17} \sqrt{2} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{351}{25330} \, \sqrt{149} \sqrt{17} \sqrt{2} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( -\frac{283}{3770} \, \sqrt{145} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{1037}{3770} \, \sqrt{13} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{413}{18850} \, \sqrt{145} \sqrt{13} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( -\frac{464}{3485} \, \sqrt{41} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{1161}{6970} \, \sqrt{17} \sqrt{2} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{889}{34850} \, \sqrt{41} \sqrt{17} \sqrt{2} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( -\frac{704}{40001} \, \sqrt{181} \sqrt{13} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{3781}{80002} \, \sqrt{17} \sqrt{13} \sqrt{2} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{925}{80002} \, \sqrt{181} \sqrt{17} \sqrt{2} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( -\frac{320}{42601} \, \sqrt{145} \sqrt{113} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{697}{85202} \, \sqrt{113} \sqrt{65} \sqrt{2} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{3069}{426010} \, \sqrt{145} \sqrt{65} \sqrt{2} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( -\frac{18751}{1380634} \, \sqrt{113} \sqrt{41} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{10323}{1380634} \, \sqrt{149} \sqrt{113} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{17475}{1380634} \, \sqrt{149} \sqrt{41} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( -\frac{21131}{3505970} \, \sqrt{181} \sqrt{65} \sqrt{2} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{25023}{3505970} \, \sqrt{149} \sqrt{65} \sqrt{2} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{10272}{1752985} \, \sqrt{181} \sqrt{149} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( -\frac{12879}{2152090} \, \sqrt{181} \sqrt{145} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{27721}{2152090} \, \sqrt{145} \sqrt{41} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{24769}{2152090} \, \sqrt{181} \sqrt{41} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$

Other formulas are:

$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( -\frac{1}{21} \, \sqrt{7} \sqrt{3} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{4}{21} \, \sqrt{7} \sqrt{3} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{2}{3} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( -\frac{1}{26} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{3}{26} \, \sqrt{13} \sqrt{3} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{3}{26} \, \sqrt{13} \sqrt{3} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( \frac{1}{133} \, \sqrt{19} \sqrt{3} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{31}{399} \, \sqrt{21} \sqrt{3} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{5}{133} \, \sqrt{21} \sqrt{19} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( -\frac{1}{91} \, \sqrt{13} \sqrt{7} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{9}{91} \, \sqrt{13} \sqrt{7} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{3}{7} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( \frac{1}{399} \, \sqrt{19} \sqrt{7} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{4}{57} \, \sqrt{21} \sqrt{7} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{10}{399} \, \sqrt{21} \sqrt{19} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( -\frac{1}{273} \, \sqrt{21} \sqrt{13} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{16}{273} \, \sqrt{21} \sqrt{13} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{4}{13} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( -\frac{31}{546} \, \sqrt{13} \sqrt{7} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{109}{546} \, \sqrt{7} \sqrt{3} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{73}{546} \, \sqrt{13} \sqrt{3} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( -\frac{4}{133} \, \sqrt{19} \sqrt{7} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{9}{133} \, \sqrt{19} \sqrt{7} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{6}{7} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( -\frac{37}{798} \, \sqrt{21} \sqrt{3} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{101}{798} \, \sqrt{19} \sqrt{3} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{25}{798} \, \sqrt{21} \sqrt{19} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( -\frac{223}{5187} \, \sqrt{21} \sqrt{13} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{311}{5187} \, \sqrt{19} \sqrt{13} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{235}{5187} \, \sqrt{21} \sqrt{19} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$

My questions are:

**Q1)** Are these formulas known or the method to generate them known?

**Q2)** Is any of this formula of some usage to someone? :-) Whatever that means.

**Q3)** Also if anyone knows of a way to further "simplify" the $a^{2k+1}+b^{2k+1}+c^{2k+1}$ to get some "nicer" formulas, that would also be nice to share.

Thanks for your help.

If there is interest, I can share the code and the method.

**Edit**:
Here are the "top ten" formulas sorted by "velocity of convergence" to $\pi$:

$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( \frac{1}{4} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{1}{4} \, \sqrt{3} \sqrt{2} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{1}{4} \, \sqrt{3} \sqrt{2} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( \frac{2}{15} \, \sqrt{5} \sqrt{3} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{1}{6} \, \sqrt{3} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{3}{10} \, \sqrt{5} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( \frac{1}{6} \, \sqrt{3} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{2}{15} \, \sqrt{5} \sqrt{3} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{3}{10} \, \sqrt{5} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( \frac{1}{8} \, \sqrt{3} \sqrt{2} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{5}{28} \, \sqrt{7} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{3}{28} \, \sqrt{7} \sqrt{3} \sqrt{2} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( \frac{1}{5} \, \sqrt{5} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{1}{10} \, \sqrt{5} \sqrt{2} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{1}{2} \, \sqrt{2} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( \frac{1}{10} \, \sqrt{5} \sqrt{2} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{1}{5} \, \sqrt{5} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{1}{2} \, \sqrt{2} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( \frac{1}{12} \, \sqrt{5} \sqrt{3} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{7}{132} \, \sqrt{11} \sqrt{6} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{1}{44} \, \sqrt{11} \sqrt{6} \sqrt{5} \sqrt{3} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( \frac{4}{91} \, \sqrt{13} \sqrt{7} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{1}{14} \, \sqrt{7} \sqrt{3} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{3}{26} \, \sqrt{13} \sqrt{3} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( \frac{5}{51} \, \sqrt{17} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{1}{3} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{3}{17} \, \sqrt{17} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( \frac{2}{77} \, \sqrt{21} \sqrt{11} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{1}{22} \, \sqrt{11} \sqrt{5} \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( \frac{1}{14} \, \sqrt{21} \sqrt{5} \right )^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}$$

**Second edit**:
Since requested, here are a few formulas where $a,b,c,L$ are integers, sorted by "error" with $N=10$ and the top ten I could find:
where we have $\epsilon, x,y,z$ and $x,y,z$ are the numbers to generate the formula,$\epsilon$ is the error to $\pi$ for $N=10$:

4.91689293680153e-6 1 2 4
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( 17 \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( 63 \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( 63 \right )^{2k+1}}{\left ( 98 \right )^{2k+1} 4^k(2k+1)}$$
0.0000153102607067801 1 2 3
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( 39 \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( 11 \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( 46 \right )^{2k+1}}{\left ( 66 \right )^{2k+1} 4^k(2k+1)}$$
0.0000209005609743684 1 2 6
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( 1353 \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( 2987 \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( 4062 \right )^{2k+1}}{\left ( 5742 \right )^{2k+1} 4^k(2k+1)}$$
0.0000342678923108686 1 2 8
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( 609 \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( 1159 \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( 1731 \right )^{2k+1}}{\left ( 2394 \right )^{2k+1} 4^k(2k+1)}$$
0.0000369975262812794 1 2 5
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( 78 \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( 34 \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( 111 \right )^{2k+1}}{\left ( 153 \right )^{2k+1} 4^k(2k+1)}$$
0.0000467633890810504 1 2 10
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( 5763 \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( 9917 \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( 15813 \right )^{2k+1}}{\left ( 21573 \right )^{2k+1} 4^k(2k+1)}$$
0.0000565682056867800 1 2 7
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( 43 \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( 23 \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( 68 \right )^{2k+1}}{\left ( 92 \right )^{2k+1} 4^k(2k+1)}$$
0.0000787760002207705 1 2 12
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( 8451 \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( 12089 \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( 21826 \right )^{2k+1}}{\left ( 29106 \right )^{2k+1} 4^k(2k+1)}$$
0.0000850493982005318 1 2 11
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( 267 \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( 175 \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( 474 \right )^{2k+1}}{\left ( 630 \right )^{2k+1} 4^k(2k+1)}$$
0.0000904264442818103 1 2 9
$$\pi = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{\left ( 309 \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( 209 \right )^{2k+1}+\left ( 559 \right )^{2k+1}}{\left ( 741 \right )^{2k+1} 4^k(2k+1)}$$

​

Comment: For the first edition see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4183066/some-formulas-for-pi).

Comment: @DietrichBurder: Got me. The method is the same, only the positive definite kernels have changed.

Comment: I think that one of the most important question would instead be: are there infinitely many values for $a, b$ and $c$? Are they related somehow?

Comment: @EllipticCurve: Yes there are infinitely many related values.

Comment: @stackExchangeUser Then again: are there integer values too? For the records: I never saw such a formula for $\pi$ but I think someone more informed than me shall answer properly. Simplification of the numerator cannot occur, unless you find interesting values (i.e. integers). Formula might be, indeed, useful provided that you are able to show they work better than the known formulas, in terms of rapidity of convergence, precision and time of computability.

Comment: Since many people apparently want to know whether $\pi$ is actually normal, such formulas might allow it to calculate later digits and make the normality somewhat more likely. I personally see little merit in calculating ever more digits of $\pi$, but I let people doing that their fun.

Comment: @EllipticCurve: Thank you for your suggestions. I see where you are heading. I could try to modify the method, since it is very flexible.

Comment: @Peter: What do you mean by "normal"?

Comment: @stackExchangeUser In a normal number, every finite digit string occurs in the expected frequency , in particular every finit digit string is in it.

Comment: Does this follow from $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k\binom{2k}{k} = 1/\sqrt{1-4x}$?

Comment: @martycohen: I am not sure. The method I use is different from what you wrote.

Comment: related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3393140/whats-the-name-of-this-surface-a2b2c22abc-1-0

Comment: also related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/343479/trigonometry-euclidean-geometry-for-natural-numbers

Comment: related: https://archive.org/details/some-formulas-for-pi

Answer (score 6):

Starting with my comment.

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k\binom{2k}{k} = \dfrac1{\sqrt{1-4x}}$

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^{2k}\binom{2k}{k} = \dfrac1{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}
$

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}\binom{2k}{k} 
= \int_0^x \dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{1-4t^2}}
=\dfrac{\arcsin(2x)}{2}
$

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{2k+1}}{2^{4k+1}(2k+1)}\binom{2k}{k} 
= \int_0^{x/2} \dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{1-4t^2}}
=\dfrac{\arcsin(x)}{2}
$

$\dfrac12\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{2k+1}}{4^{2k}(2k+1)}\binom{2k}{k} 
= \int_0^{x/2} \dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{1-4t^2}}
=\dfrac{\arcsin(x)}{2}
$

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{2k+1}}{4^{2k}(2k+1)}\binom{2k}{k} 
=\arcsin(x)
$

$2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{a^{2k+1}+b^{2k+1}+c^{2k+1}}{4^{2k}(2k+1)}\binom{2k}{k} 
=2(\arcsin(a)+\arcsin(b)+\arcsin(c))
$

so we want
$\dfrac{\pi}{2}
=\arcsin(a)+\arcsin(b)+\arcsin(c)
$

Comment: Nice, But how do you find $a,b,c$?

Comment: I don't know. But I think this is a start.

Comment: It should be $2^{2n+1}$ not $2^{4n+1}$ in your formula for $\frac{1}{2}\arcsin x$.

Comment: I think the resulting condition is  $$\left( \sqrt {1-{b}^{2}}a+\sqrt {1-{a}^{2}}b \right) \sqrt {1-{c}^{2}}-c \left( ab-\sqrt {1-{a}^{2}}\sqrt {1-{b}^{2}} \right) = 1$$